# brew update unable to access github

Tags: macos, ssl, openssl, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to run brew update and getting this message:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

I'm really unsure what this is telling me. I ran brew upgrade and it seems to have gone about its business fine, but I just can't get the update to work. I'm behind a corporate proxy and have set http/s_proxy to my credentials using http (not https).

I'm running:

```
OSX 10.13.6
git version 2.13.6
brew 1.2.2-51-g1ef00aaf
```

Thinking it might be git, I also tried doing

```
brew install git
```

which installed ok, but brew update failed again though with this message:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/': SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled
```

Is there a way to resolve or at least get more information about what's happening?